# Converting GDCM Image to Java BufferedImage

Tags: java, bufferedimage, dicom

I am using GDCM to read in DICOM images.  Is there an easy way to read in a dicom file with GDCM, and then convert it to a Java BufferedImage?  So far I have the following

```
String filename = "C:\\test.dcm";
    gdcm.ImageReader reader = new gdcm.ImageReader();
    reader.SetFileName(filename);
    reader.Read();
    gdcm.Image image = reader.GetImage();
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage((int)image.GetRows(, (int)image.GetColumns(), BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_GRAY);
    // How do I populate bufferedImage?;
```

Can anyone tell me if I'm on the right track and how to complete this example.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the raw buffer of pixel using:

```
  byte[] str1 = new byte[ image.GetBufferLength()];
  image.GetBuffer( str1 );
```

See full example at:

- http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/ScanDirectory_8java-example.html

or

- https://sourceforge.net/p/gdcm/gdcm/ci/master/tree/Examples/Java/ScanDirectory.java

or even

- https://github.com/malaterre/GDCM/blob/master/Examples/Java/ScanDirectory.java

Comment: For me, image.GetBuffer(str1) is throwing an exception.  Specifically, image.GetBuffer() takes in a gdcm.SWIGTYPE_p_<type> where <type> = short, float, byte, double, etc.  How do I convert from gdcm.SWIGTYPE_p_<type> to a Java array?

Comment: The link is dead you can find the full example at: http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/ScanDirectory_8java-example.html