# Displaying DICOM images on android

Tags: android, dicom

I want to display a DICOM image on android. Is there any way to convert a DICOM image to JPEG on android?

Currently the default conversion of DICOM to bitmap returns `null`. Any idea how to proceed ?

Comment: What is a Dicom image?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739349/how-to-access-dicom-file-on-android-os http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094508/converting-dicom-image-to-jpeg-image

Comment: Thanks for reply.I already checked the above links..But the BufferedImage and ImageIo classes are java specific and not supported in android.

Comment: [Here](https://code.google.com/p/dicom-droid/) is an old attempt to provide DICOM functionality for Android. I have no idea how well it functions, especially with the later versions of Android, but it might be worth giving it a try at least.

Comment: I did use the dicom droid library.But the resulting image is not proper.The image is not clear

Comment: If your programming language is java checkout [the answer here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657817/converting-gdcm-image-to-java-bufferedimage

Answer (score 2):

[Imebra](https://imebra.com) provides Java bindings for android and the documentation shows how to extract an image ready to be displayed:

```
   // Allocate a transforms chain: contains all the transforms to execute before displaying
    //  an image. Can be empty
    TransformsChain transformsChain = new TransformsChain();

    // Let's use a DrawBitmap object to generate a buffer with the pixel data. We will
    // use that buffer to create an Android Bitmap
    com.imebra.dicom.DrawBitmap drawBitmap = new com.imebra.dicom.DrawBitmap(image, transformsChain);

    int temporaryBuffer[] = new int[1]; // Temporary buffer. Just used to get the needed buffer size
    int bufferSize = drawBitmap.getBitmap(image.getSizeX(), image.getSizeY(), 0, 0, image.getSizeX(), image.getSizeY(), temporaryBuffer, 0);
    int buffer[] = new int[bufferSize]; // Ideally you want to reuse this in subsequent calls to getBitmap()

    // Now fill the buffer with the image data and create a bitmap from it
    drawBitmap.getBitmap(image.getSizeX(), image.getSizeY(), 0, 0, image.getSizeX(), image.getSizeY(), buffer, bufferSize);

    Bitmap renderBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(buffer, image.getSizeX(), image.getSizeY(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(renderBitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you are using Java is looking into DCM4CHE.
It's an open source library to read/write and manipulate DICOM files.
Reading is as easy as this:

```
DicomInputStream din = new DicomInputStream(new File("your_image.dcm"));
DicomObject doj = din.readDicomObject();
```

The `DicomObject` then contains all kinds of data. There's a neat documentation over here (https://dcm4che.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/proj/overview?mode=global)

There are certainly easier options to be fair, but if reading and displaying the image is all you want, you might as well give it a shot.

Comment: I am new to android, please tell me how to integrate DCM4CHE into my Android studio and same can I integrate in ios also.. @David Bauer